# Visual Studio 2015 "non-standard syntax; use '&' to create pointer for member"

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm creating a quick game and I used a different class file for inputting player names. I keep getting the specified error :

> use '&' to create pointer for member

when I am trying to call the function from main.

The function `getPlayerOne` and `getPlayerTwo` are public functions. I think it's because I'm changing the `player1` value so I need a pointer but when I try to add a pointer it gives me the same error.

How do I edit values of strings using pointers?

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//Included Header Files
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Player players;
    cout << players.getPlayerOne << endl;
    cout << players.getPlayerTwo << endl;

}
```

Player.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:

    //Initialize player1
    void getPlayerOne(string &playerOne);
    void getPlayerTwo(string &playerTwo);


    Player();
private:

    //Players
    string player1;
    string player2;
};
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player()
{
}

void Player::getPlayerOne(string &playerOne) {
    cout << "Enter player 1 name: \n";
    cin >> playerOne;
    cout << playerOne << " is a great name!\n";
    player1 = playerOne;
}

void Player::getPlayerTwo(string &playerTwo) {
    cout << "Enter player 2 name: \n";
    cin >> playerTwo;
    cout << playerTwo << " is a great name!\n";

    player2 = playerTwo;
}
```

I could probably just put the `Player` code in main because it's so small, but I think it is better to have separate classes when (eventually) I can program files with more characters.

Comment: What is `cout << players.getPlayerOne << endl;` trying to do? It makes no sense.

Comment: I think you're confused.  Why are you declaring the function to take one string parameter?  In addition, why are you calling the function without parentheses?   That's what's confusing -- you declared the function to take one parameter, but you attempt (even though it failed) to call it with no parameters.

Comment: You must use `( )` to call a function. Otherwise the compiler thinks you are trying to refer to the function without calling it.  Also, `getPlayerOne` does not return a value, so `cout << players.getPlayerOne()` would be illegal.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it. I needed to take out the cout and just put them just player.getPlayerOne(); with a string as a parameter if that makes any sense. Thanks for trying to help :) I gotta go over my questions before I submit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 function named `getPlayerX(string & name)` returning nothing :
I think you made a mistake in what are "getters" and "setters".

You want your `std::cout` to **GET** a string, then make your functions `getPlayerX()` like a **GETTER** :

```
std::string getPlayerX() const noexcept;
```

You want to **SET** your data, make a **SETTER** :

```
void setPlayerX(const std::string & name);
```

Remember, the function you use are like this :

```
Type_you_want_to_get   Name_of_the_function ([const] type_of_argument [&] var_name)
```

**void** "means" return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to call the functions with parameters since they already had cout and cin statements in them. Silly mistake.

```
string player1;
string player2;

int main() {

    Player players;
    players.getPlayerOne(player1);
    players.getPlayerTwo(player2);

}
```

Comment: Why bother with the class, in this case?

Comment: Later, when I have more than just two players, It will be more useful so I decided why not practice using a classes so i get into that habit and learn how to use classes better.

Comment: This class won't help you have more than two players. If you had a `Player` class for *one* player you could do something like `Player p1, p2, p3; p1.getPlayerName(); p2.getPlayerName(); p3.getPlayerName();`.

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that. Better quit for the night.